# Capture incoming and outgoing soap request

Tags: c#, soap, web-services

I have a C# console application that calls SSRS soap based webservice (service runs on a remote machine). I want to capture the incoming and outgoing soap request.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this just for debugging purposes? If so, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is probably your best bet. [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) is also great, but it doesn't do the HTTPS stuff that Fiddler does.

It's possible to capture the data on the service side by effectively adding an incoming and outgoing filter which just passes the data along, logging it as it goes - but that's *slightly* fiddly from what I remember. Worth the effort if you're trying to do this for long-term audit etc, but for simple inspection I'd go with Fiddler.

Comment: thanks jon. I just want this for debugging purposes..I tried using fiddler but it is not detecting the calls made from my C# proxy class to the webservice (runs on remote machine). It is however detecting the internet traffic.

Any suggestions what could be missing from my settings?

Comment: Are you wanting to capture traffic between your box and a network box, or between two separate network boxes that are not your box?

Comment: my bad. its detecting the traffic. 

@drachenstern: its between my box and a network box.

Comment: Ok, just making sure, because if it wasn't detecting traffic you were probably looking at something a lot more complex ... Fiddler2 is pretty excellent...

Comment: Just installed fiddler for this same problem.  Got it working & inspecting the xml within about 2 minutes of install.  Too easy!

Comment: Worth adding here is also TCP mon from apache. And wireshark does HTTPS also.